# Using jqMath on Android treating "\t" as an escape character

Tags: java, android, jqmath

I have used jqMath for displaying Math equations using a WebView.

Here's the code for Math equation

$(\table \cos θ, - \sin θ; \sin θ, \cos θ)$

Expected output:
[image]

But the output is this:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
 String js = Constants.JQ_MATH_BEGIN +string+Constants.JQ_MATH_END;
 holder.webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(Constants.PATH,js,  "text/html",  "UTF-8",null);
```

I could solve it by changing the string code to

`$(\\table \cos θ, - \sin θ; \sin θ, \cos θ)$`

and the equation is shown properly. But, I also want to display equations on a website from the same database, but this code doesn't work with the double slash on browsers. So keeping two columns is not a good solution.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the replace function.

```
String escaped = str.replace("\\t","\\\\t");
```

Don't know why that was happening, though.